# Html form generated with PHP not inserting all Arrays

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that was generated with php

Below is in my account.php
$student_id is set by a session and I am finding all the file_names that are associated with that student_id. The I generated an HTML form using php where each of the file_names for that student are displayed in a checkbox format with a description input below each checkbox.

```
<?php 
$find = mysql_query("SELECT file_name FROM chemlab_files WHERE student_id = 
'$student_id'") or die  ("Could not search!");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
$file_name = $row['file_name'];
$_SESSION['file_name'] = $file_name;
echo "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='file_name[]'    
value='{$file_name}'>$file_name</label><br><input type='text' name='description[]'    
value='' placeholder='description'>";
}
?>
```

This is now part of the handler.php I am having trouble with it does insert but it insert blanks for the checkboxes not checked off

```
if(is_array($_POST['description'])){
foreach(str_replace('#', '', $_POST['description']) as $strip){ 
                $description_backslash = $strip . '/';
                $description = mysql_real_escape_string($strip);
                $query = "INSERT INTO file_list(description) VALUE ('$description')";
                $q= mysql_query($query) or die ('Error posting data');
                //print_r($description);
                //print '<br>';
            }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: while we're at it, you're potentially vulnerable to HTML injection/XSS as well.  find a template engine that can escape for you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes that are not checked, do not get sent to the server so if not all checkboxes are checked, there will be a mis-match between the checkbox indices and the `file_name` inputs.

To avoid that problem, you would have to add indices to your form fields so that you know what `description` belongs to what `file_name` and to be able to loop over the `description`'s and discard the ones that are not set.